# work from any device to send request from vuejs online to laravel locally

Tags: laravel, vue.js, hosting

I publish my only frontend `Vuejs` on the internet

and my backend `laravel` it works on my local pc and its have the internet and

so I want send any request from  `vuejs` to laravel on any device

how should this work laravel backend works locally and vue js is worked online ?

I put **unique port** with `php artisan serve --port`

in order to work always.

Comment: I would not recommend using you local machine as a public server! If it's just for testing, you could use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [expose](https://expose.dev/). If it's not just for testing, then you should host the application on an actual server.

Comment: I want to access the laravel by any device not on the same lan network but with any device work on the internet >> Note: I want my laravel project work only on my pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is go to public ip by using NAT

in order to translate **local ip** to **public ip**